# Can I use "tho/though" just like when I use "because" or "but"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, difference

In my country, to be precise, the dialect in my country (not English) is often using a sentence like this (for convenience reason since it's an English site, I'll try to translate into English):

Instead of we say like English like this:

> **Because** I don't like her.

> **But** I don't like her!

In my country, we often say like this:

> I don't like her, **because**.

> I don't like her, **but**!

Yes, we often put *because* and *but* at the end of a sentence. Anyway, when I read a sentence that uses tho like I got from UrbanDictionary below:

> **[tho](http://tho.urbanup.com/8202431)**
>
> An overused form of the word 'though' Usually placed at the end of
> sentences
>
> - That hair **tho**.
>
> **[tho](http://tho.urbanup.com/8390080)**
>
> short form for "though" Mostly used with teens and in SMS
>
> - Person one: But you do not feel like that do you?
> - Person two: no but i kinda do **tho**.

Every time I see that word used like that, I never have a clue as why they use like that. If **tho** means **though = although = however**, I don't think that makes sense. Or perhaps, have I been misunderstood by its real meaning regardlss it's used in *formal* or *non-formal* situation?

I'm always thinking that the word **tho** used in those sentences don't have meaning and just the way people who want to sound like American/have cool English. Anyway, can you tell me the difference if **tho** in informal turns out absolutely different from **though** in formal situation?

Back to the original problem, does **tho** here have the meaning like **because or but** but used at the end of a sentence just like the dialect in my country?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the teenage language you describe, but it's standard colloquial English to say something like "Most people think she's charming. I don't like her, though".  Here, _though_ means _in spite of what I said in the previous sentence_.

Comment: I see ‘tho’ mainly used in jokes when written like that. I’m not sure if this is a common use, but from what I see it seems like it.